# Mapping Gestures to key commands

Tags: java, hook, keypress, gesture, leap-motion

I'm currently starting to develop for Leap Motion and I want to map certain gestures that the leap picks up to OS Hooks (specifically OSX).

For example, a hand movement downward would lower the screen brightness, and upward would increase the brightness. Another would be a gesture to increase/decrease volume, switch apps, etc.

1. I'm wondering if any libraries exist in Java that would act as an interface/api to these hooks/system settings?
2. Would it be a better idea to just simulate the key press combinations?

I've done a lot of research on the first and found some complicated ideas like mach_injection and a few others but I don't think that's what I'm looking for. I found this link but I'm not 100% sure this is even what I'm looking for: http://gestureworks.com/blogs/news/7299746-gesturekey-maps-multitouch-gestures-to-key-commands

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `java.awt.robot`.
You can use Robot to emulate keypressess and mouse events on any operating system that runs J2SE

[Java 6 Robot class documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress%28int)

Next you still need to detect the gestures, but Leap's own API should make that pretty straight forward.